# How to encode pauses in Garmin Fit files

Tags: java, garmin

I'd like to export an activity with GPS coordinates as Garmin FIT file.
This activity contains a pause. During this pause, position and height changes dramatically (let's say a shuttle moving to the top of a mountain). I don't want this move be counted as activity: distance and elevation gain should be neutral for statistics.

How can I construct my FIT file to exclude this movement during pause?

I've tried to create laps (`LapMessage`), set startPosition and endPosition for each active lap (GPX track-segment), but when importing FIT file to STRAVA, it counts distance moved during pause as if it was part of the activity.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1: Just ignore the pause and shrink the time.

Solution 2. Issue Event Messages for a timer: `event = timer`, `event_type` is `start` or `stop`.

1. Start the timer before the first `RecordMessage`.
2. Stop the timer when the pause begins (no messages are issued duting the pauase).
3. Start the timer when the pause stops. Continue with `time_from_course` for the `RecordMessage`.
4. Stop the timer at the end.

E.g.:

```
# start
event 14:09:10: type: timer, event_type: start
record 14:09:10: time_from_course: 0, ...
...
record 14:09:22: time_from_course: 12,...
event 14:15:13: type: timer, event_type: stop
event 14:20:07: type: timer, event_type: start
record 14:20:08: time_from_course: 13,...
...
event 15:45:39: type: timer, event_type: stop
# end
```

Note: Garmin connect parses such FIT well, however Strava computes the moving time wrong - with the pause.